# Check if file exists using full paths and wildcard for filename bash

Tags: bash

I need to be able to check if a filename with a certain string exists within a directory of files using bash. In this example I want to check if there are files that contain the date `20171101` in their filename:

```
[ -e "/path/to/data/dir/*20171101*" ] && echo true || echo false
```

When I use `find *20171101*` within the directory it returns the files containing that date. However when I try the same method on the full path I get a `binary operator expected` error. This is both for -e and find.

What I need is to be able to search files **using a wildcard** and the **full path** and **echo true/false** when the condition is met. There can be multiple files, but it should return true when at least 1 file is found that meets the condition. Furthermore I need to **execute it in 1 line**. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[ -n "$(find /path/to/data/dir -name '*20171101*' | head -1)" ] && ...
```

The quoting is important to prevent the shell from expanding it in the current directory.  You need to use `test -n` because `find` alone won't tell you if it found matches or not.  The `head -1` stops when it finds a match, so you don't waste time looking for more.

Comment: Tested it on different path names and wildcards. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @John can you please explain more about the "-n" test? I can't google more examples/explanation of that. Thanks!

Comment: @ddss12 `test -n` aka `[ -n ... ]` succeeds if the string length is nonzero.